# Image File Execution Options equivalent on os x

Tags: xcode, macos, clang

Is there an equivalent of [Image File Execution Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) on OS X ?

1) Is there any kind of Xcode API that will let you automatically attach the debugger to Xcode when a particular process is launched ?

OR

2) Is there some kind of API call that you can do that will automatically prompt you to attach the debugger to your process ?

Answer (score 3):

There is no equivalent of that API on OS X.

The closest you can come that I'm aware of is using Xcode's "Wait for application to launch" option for debugging, which will fire up the debugger and then attach to the application as soon as it sees it launched. This is also available in both `gdb` and `lldb` on the command line, if that's more your thing.